# Typescript: Type 'X' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So I have a React Native application using TypeScript, with an error that's driving me crazy.

Basically, there is a Searchable List. It is initiated with an Array of values. Once the user types in a SearchBar, the initiated Array is filtered, returning an updated Array.

However, TypeScript gives me the error: `Type '{ id: string; name: string; selected: boolean; }[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.`

I am confused because I don't know where this `'(prevState: undefined): undefined'`actually comes from and why. Do you know what I am doing wrong here? Help will be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
const defaultChoices = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'default',
    selected: false,
  },
];

let choicesList;

const getChoicesList = () => {
  if (listName === 'include') {
    choicesList = Object.values(includeChoices).map(choice => ({
      ...choice,
    }));
  } else if (listName === 'exclude') {
    choicesList = Object.values(excludeChoices).map(choice => ({
      ...choice,
    }));
  }
};

const [filteredChoicesList, setFilteredChoicesList] = useState(choicesList);

useEffect(() => {
  getChoicesList();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    let choices = defaultChoices;

    if (listName === 'include') {
      choices = includeChoices;
    } else if (listName === 'exclude') {
      choices = excludeChoices;
    } else {
      choices = defaultChoices;
    }

    const newChoices = choices.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`; // ignore Uppercase/Lowercase and make equal
      const textData = query.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });

    setFilteredChoicesList(newChoices); // error occurs for "newChoices"
  }, [effect]);
```

Comment: Not sure whether that will resolve the error but you should probably initialize `choicesList` (and thereby the state's array) to `[]`. Also, not a Typescript expert, but aren't you supposed to state types when declaring vars and params?

Comment: Please give a [mre], that code seems very convoluted. Why do you use `\`${item.name.toUpperCase()}\`` on one line but the (simpler) equivalent `query.toUpperCase()` on the next, for example? And shouldn't the logic for including or excluding items reverse the comparison, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, you have set the `choicesList` as undefined. and `getChoicesList` is called on the first initialization of component but before that the state us being set where the `choicesList` is undefined.

Update the part of your code as

```
let choicesList: any[] = [];

const getChoicesList = () => {
  let data: any[] = [];
  if (listName === 'include') {
    data = Object.values(includeChoices).map(choice => ({
      ...choice,
    }));
  } else if (listName === 'exclude') {
    data = Object.values(excludeChoices).map(choice => ({
      ...choice,
    }));
  }
  return data;
};

const [filteredChoicesList, setFilteredChoicesList] = useState<any[]>(choicesList);

useEffect(() => {
  const updatedList = getChoicesList();
  setFilteredChoicesList(updatedList)
}, []);
```

Now, you'll have the `filteredChoicesList` with data you need and you shouldn't have any compilation error. 
Another thing is, create an interface and replace `any` with that interface in the state and while defining.